# APN Device Token Encoding when using ColdFusion com.notnoop.apns.SimpleApnsNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, coldfusion, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an iOS app dealing with push notifications. Our push notification server is written in ColdFusion and is using `com.notnoop.apns.SimpleApnsNotification` to send the notifications. In the app, I grab the device token (`NSData`) and Base64 encode it before sending it off to the server. However, while the `SimpleApnsNotification` api is expecting a String for the token, it doesn't appear to want a Base64 encoded String.

Do you know what encoding `SimpleApnsNotification` is expecting for the device token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to hex encode it.  Try making a Category on NSData with this method in it (this worked great for me):

```
 - (NSString*) hexEncode {
NSString *deviceToken = [[self description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""];
deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] ;
deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
return deviceToken;
}
```

Give that a try and see if it works for you, too.